# USB 2.0 to IDE & SATA Adapter - how do you install Windows XP

Tags: usb, sata, adapter, pata

My laptop [CD-ROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM) is no longer working, and I need to format the hard drive and reload Windows XP. My laptop is [Fujitsu Siemens AMILO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujitsu_Siemens_Computers#Products). I purchased an 'EASY IDE' adaptor, followed the instuction to set up the adaptor, and connected the laptop hard drive.

It found the hard drive and assigned the drive as, E:\ drive. Now this is as far as I have got, because there was no instructions as to how I should reload Windows on the hard drive. Having said this, I do believe that I have formated the hard disk drive, but what do I do next?

Answer (score 2):

You have two different problems here.

1) XP [doesn't like](http://www.ngine.de/article/id/8) being installed on an external USB drive.

2) You can't install Windows to a fresh drive from inside of an existing Windows install.

What you should have done is purchased an external DVD/CD drive. Then the procedure that you would follow is boot to the XP CD and follow the normal way to install Windows on an internal drive.

Comment: @MarkM: A good suggestion. However, depending on how old this "Fujitsu Siemens Amilo" laptop is, the BIOS on it may not allow booting from a USB attached optical drive. Hard to tell without the exact series and model number information to identify which "Amilo" he has. Looking at the Fujitsu support site, there were apparently a LOT of them. http://ts.fujitsu.com/support/index.html

Comment: Hi - Me again, I have six Xp floppy disks for loading Windows, everything goes just fine until I put the last disk, disk 6 into the floppy drive, then it freezes up the the stop error blue screen appears. The floppy version of Windows I have three sets of six disks Xp XP2 Xp1 and each set does the same at disk six

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure if this message was sent - My Amilo serial number is Nr YSLSQ013179  AMILO L7320GW reg No. LM13+ (8Q6800004 - I do have an external DVD/CD drive - I entered the system Bios in the boot menu I selected 'USB Storerage Disk' saved and exit the next screen appeared "Operating System not found" - rebooted and selected F12 for the Boot Menu, there  was the three option (2) - IDE 0: Fujitsu MHV2060AT - (PM. (4) - CD-ROM/DVD-ROM. (5) - Boot from LAN. Now in this menu there is no USB selection

Comment: Hi - Just one more thing, I also have an external Hard drive if this can help in anyway
Thanks

Comment: @Mal - it sounds like you can boot from CD via USB then. I would get a cheap USB CD/DVD drive and install Windows from that.

Comment: Hi- As previously mentioned, I have tried a USB external CD drive and altered the Bios to Boot from USB but it doesn't work. I select on Boot F12 for Boot menu and there is not a USB option?? yet there is on the Bios option??

Comment: Hi Me Again - I have managed to place Windows on the laptop hard drive, now this is where I'm a little green. I refitted the hard drive back into the laptop, booted up only to receive a message 'No Operating System', god a thought I cracked it! Please please can any body help. Many thanks, waiting in hope.